# publish action approved appearing in time line but not showing in user or friend's news feed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, publish

I have registered my website as app on facebook and i have got publish actions approved.
My problem is the action is coming in activity on facebook but neither aggregation is working nor it is showing in user or user's friend's news feed.

Please let me know who it works

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the actions published if you go to:
`http://www.facebook.com/{facebook_id}/app_{app_namespace}`?

If you see the actions in the above page, it means that actions are working correctly, but Facebook is just displaying the actions differently on the timeline / friends' newsfeed. This is actually normal.

Most actions are published to the `Activity` part of the wall. Facebook randomly post an action by itself or use aggregations to display something on the user's wall. But it's not always the same.

Comment: Yes actions are shown correctly but they are not aggregated as for other apps and also app is not showing on timeline.

Comment: If you are using the built-in `Read` action, then you won't have a dedicated box in the timeline. I've seen this with my own app. But custom actions generate a box on the timeline and have a better chance of using aggregations.

Comment: I tried using custom action but got the following error :Status: Changes needed
You are trying to submit a custom action which is not permitted. Please delete this action and submit a built-in version of this action instead.
Please make changes below and resubmit for review.

Comment: That explains it. The build-in read action has less preference over aggregations. Nothing you can do about it since Facebook won't allow you a custom action for the same thing.

Comment: have you used custom action??

Comment: I had to use build-in action for one of my apps, but another one got away with using custom action. Both use `read`, but the one with custom action works better.

Comment: how your custom action got approved??

Comment: is there any way to assign custom objects to build in actions?

Comment: You can create actions separate from objects, but in order to use them you will need to create a custom action, as the build-in one cannot be edited.

Comment: oh then i m stuck as facebook is not allowing me to create custom actions

Comment: If you keep modifying your aggregations, it won't work either. Try performing lots of actions and then see if the aggregations work. My aggregations took a few days to get working.

Comment: you mean to say your build in actions